# EF6 - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, datareader, actionresult

I am coding a MVC5 internet application and am using EF6.

I have an `Edit` `ActionResult` that is called when an `Asset` object is edited. I also need to update other objects values when an `Asset` object is edited. The `UpdateAssociatedAssetObjects` function does this.

I am getting the following error:

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

In the `UpdateAssociatedAssetObjects` function, at the following line of code:

```
if (item.mapMarker.Id == asset.Id)
```

Here is the `Edit ActionResult`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(AssetViewModel assetViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(assetViewModel.asset).State = EntityState.Modified;
        assetViewModel.asset.lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        if (assetViewModel.asset.linkFromExternalResource)
        {
            assetViewModel.asset.webAddress = assetViewModel.webAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            assetViewModel.asset.webAddress = assetViewModel.filename;
        }
        db.Entry(assetViewModel.asset).Property(uco => uco.creationDate).IsModified = false;
        db.Entry(assetViewModel.asset).Property(uco => uco.userName).IsModified = false;
        assetService.UpdateAssociatedAssetObjects(db, assetViewModel.asset);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(assetViewModel);
}
```

Here is the `UpdateAssociatedAssetObjects` function:

```
public void UpdateAssociatedAssetObjects(CanFindLocationDatabaseContext db, Asset asset)
{
    foreach (var item in db.mapLocations)
    {
        if (item.mapMarker.Id == asset.Id)
        {
            item.lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Can I please have some help with this code?

I have tried placing the `UpdateAssociatedAssetObjects` function after the `await db.SaveChangesAsync()` and using a new database context object, but the error still occurs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the connection string look like?

Comment: The connection string is all working. Objects are successfully being added and removed. Do you think the problem would be with the connection string?

Comment: Maybe, that's why I asked :)

Comment: Can you help with the problem in the OP?

Comment: Why don't you show the connection string?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21131596/1470747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller method you are already opening a db connection to an entry of asset.

In your method UpdateAssociatedAssetObjects you're trying to open a second db connection reading, while you're main is still open. Get the first object or get the list in the second object.

An alternate solution is to update the db twice.