# How to show submitted form data in Umbraco forms

Tags: c#, forms, razor, umbraco

I'm searching for a way to display the submitted form data on the next page -
 Using "Umbraco forms" in Umbraco 7.6.3.

I've tried the available methods on https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Products/UmbracoForms/Developer/Working-With-Data/ but most of the methods returns nothing or throws the "There is already an open DataReader" error.

Comment: The DataReader issue is probably because you're trying to access the database while it's being read somewhere else. Checkout to fix this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21131596/2963111

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a [custom workflow](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Products/UmbracoForms/Developer/Extending/Adding-a-Workflowtype) which sets a variable which stores the form submission ID to the users session.

Then, when the user checks out the next page, you can query for that submission and display what was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [Form Editor](https://github.com/kjac/FormEditor/) instead. It's got this among other features built-in and documented - see [these tutorials](https://github.com/kjac/FormEditor/blob/master/Docs/submissions.md).