# IDbCommand missing ExecuteReaderAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-core-2.0

I'm using .NET Core 2.0. I've got the following function that calls `IDbCommand.ExecuteReader`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Widget>> ReadAllAsync(
    System.Data.IDbConnection databaseConnection,
    System.Data.IDbTransaction databaseTransaction)
{
    var commandText = "SELECT WidgetId, Name FROM Widget";

    // _databaseCommandFactory.Create returns an IDbCommand
    var command = this._databaseCommandFactory.Create(databaseConnection, databaseTransaction, commandText);

    using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // iterate through the data reader converting a collection of Widgets (`IEnumerable<Widget>`)
    }
}
```

I get a warning

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

I was thinking about converting the `command.ExecuteReader()` statement to `await Task.Run(() => command.ExecuteReader())` as advised in the warning. But I'm not sure this is the correct approach, I believe `Task.Run(...)` is for doing CPU based work. This is primarily IO work.

So my questions are

1. Is `Task.Run(...)` the correct approach?
2. If not, is there another solution?
3. Or should I just ignore the warning for now and wait until `ExecuteReaderAsync` gets added to the `IDbCommand` interface? (is there a plan for this?)

Comment: `IDbCommand` is unlikely to get `ExecuteReaderAsync` any time soon -- it could break existing implementations that have no support for async/await. `DbCommand`, however, does have it, and all framework implementations of `IDbCommand` inherit from it, so it's no great risk to cast it.

Comment: I second what JeroenMostert said. You could always check for DbCommand and if viable, cast to it so you have access to the async member.

Comment: You could also consider using [StackExchange.Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: @Nkosi I'm currently seeing what I can do with the framework as-is i.e. not introducing third party components unless absolutely necessary. It's going well so far. I will have a look at Dapper though.

Comment: You shall consider using Dapper Micro ORM, as it makes working with Ado.net much simpler and has all the Async options available. Needn't even worry about opening / closing the connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `await` keyword is what allows the method to run asynchronously. The `async` keyword enables the use of the `await` keyword within the method and assists in managing the return.

Until `await` is called the method will run synchronously.

So all of this runs synchronously. It will not return anything or move through the method until it has completed.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Widget>> ReadAllAsync(
    System.Data.IDbConnection databaseConnection,
    System.Data.IDbTransaction databaseTransaction)
{
    var commandText = "SELECT WidgetId, Name FROM Widget";

    // _databaseCommandFactory.Create returns an IDbCommand
    var command = this._databaseCommandFactory.Create(databaseConnection, databaseTransaction, commandText);

    using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // iterate through the data reader converting a collection of Widgets (`IEnumerable<Widget>`)
    }
}
```

By casting to `DbCommand`, which most `IDbCommand` derived implementations already do, then casting to `DbCommand` and adding await would work e.g.

```
var dbCommand = (DbCommand) command;
using (var dataReader = await dbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    while (await dataReader.ReadAsync()) 
    {
        // iterate through the data reader converting a collection of Widgets (`IEnumerable<Widget>`)
    }
}
```

or creating a separate Task

```
public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
  // Do your stuff that takes a long time
}

public async Task CallMyAsyncMethod()
{
  // We can await Tasks, regardless of where they come from.
  await MyAsyncMethod();

}
```

This way - the program will continue while awaiting the return from this method, rather than locking up the UI and all else.

Comment: `(DbCommand) command` has the courtesy of failing immediately with an `InvalidCastException`. Getting the object with `as`, then using it, just opens you up to a mysterious `NullReferenceException`. If you think you know what the type is, and you're not prepared to handle errors, just hard cast.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was inspecting Dapper and they do the same thing within their extension methods. They don't expose confusing implementation concerns like what I was suggesting in my answer. Nice catch.

Comment: Thanks @YvetteColomb. I've decided to cast to DbCommand for now. I'm not entirely sure how creating a seperate task would help. Would that not just move the problem to a different method and I'd still get all the warnings?

Comment: Looks like casting to DbCommand has caused a few problems. I'm getting a "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." exception when I try to get data for a second time (refresh a page). My connection and transaction are wrapped in usings so not sure whats happening.

Comment: @KevinBrydon try wrapping the command as well. Also take a look at this answer re that last error https://stackoverflow.com/a/21131596/5233410

Comment: Hi @YvetteColomb. Thanks for your help. I'm still getting issues with the "...Command must be closed first" and "This connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets". I've got everything I can think of in `using` blocks so I'll have to investigate my code a bit deeper. I don't want to enable MultipleActiveResultSets until I know that's the correct solution.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm not sure I want to enable MultipleActiveResultSets until I really understand what that means. Need to do more reading. And I'm pretty sure the root issue lies in my design/implementation.

Comment: @YvetteColomb False alarm. My code was at fault. Had a method that should have been returning a Task but was returning void. Inside that method was a call to one of my asyncronous repositories. Lesson learned!

Comment: Multiple active result set is mechanism through which multiple result sets can be fetched from the database in a single round trip, like in Sql server management studio we can fire multiple select statements and their results are listed one after another. This is a `DataReader` feature accessed using `NextResult` call, check if there's an explicit call to fetch the multiple result sets