# SqlBulkCopy error (There is already an open DataReader...)

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to make an exact copy from one sql table to another. Both tables reside in the same database. I am trying to use SqlBulkCopy but receive a "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." error.

I have found many similar problems and tried the solutions contained therein with no success. I am very new to this so any help with this (or any of the code below) is appreciated.

```
SqlCommand readLocal = new SqlCommand("Select CompanyNumber,CompanyName,AccessNumber,TruckName,TransferStartTime,TransferEndTime,TransferVolume FROM TransfersNew", conLocal);

try
{
    conLocal.Open();
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conLocal))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TransfersHistory";

        try
        {
            using (SqlDataReader readerLocal = readLocal.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (readerLocal.Read())
                {
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(readerLocal);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Globals.infoString = ex.Message;
            Globals.infoStringColor = true;
            var newForm = new pagePopupInfo();
            newForm.ShowDialog();
        }
        finally
        {
            conLocal.Close();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Globals.infoString = ex.Message;
    Globals.infoStringColor = true;
    var newForm = new pagePopupInfo();
    newForm.ShowDialog();
}
finally
{
    conLocal.Close();
}
```

I'm wide open to suggestions. Thanks

Matheus' suggestion worked. My additional issue regarding not copying the data turned out to be that it was just not copying the first record. I changed my code to this to correct that issue:

```
try
        {
            conLocal.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conLocal))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TransfersHistory";
                SqlDataReader readerLocal = readLocal.ExecuteReader();
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(readerLocal);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" when using 2 distinct commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475195/error-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-mu)

Comment: Add MultipleActiveResultSets=true to your connection string. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/h32h3abf(v=vs.100))

Comment: I followed Matheus' suggestion and I no longer get the error, so thanks for that. However it also did not copy the data to the TransfersHistory table. So I'll dig into that and report back.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you have two Using, one inside the another, so it is considered as two connections.

You can try something like this :

```
                   using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conLocal))
                   using (SqlDataReader readerLocal = readLocal.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (readerLocal.Read())
                        {
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(readerLocal);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produced the same result. Thanks

Comment: Same error. Using MultipleActiveResultSets=true in my connection string worked to resolve the issue. Thanks